# Multipart form data upload with multiple images + parameters (Alamofire 5.2)

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to upload multiple images and parameters to the server using 'Alamofire 5.2)'
This is what the server expects

```
[{"key":"media1","description":"","type":"file","value":["/C:/Users/x/x/x/x.jpg"]},
[{"key":"media2","description":"","type":"file","value":["/C:/Users/x/x/x/x.jpg"]},
[{"key":"media3","description":"","type":"file","value":["/C:/Users/x/x/x/x.jpg"]},

{"key":"model","value":"{\"emp_Id\": \"6\",\"device_Identifier\":\"Device 01\",\"timestamp\":\"123\,”\description\”:\”description\",”handoverStatus”:”false”}","type":"text"}]

//Please note the array part
```

This is how i add picked image to an image array

```
var dictImage : [UIImage]?

if pickedImage.pngData() != nil
{
  dictImage!.append(pickedImage)
}
```

This is how im trying to call the alamofire upload

```
func xyz()
{
        let param : [String: Any] = [
            "emp_Id" : "",
            "device_Identifier" : "",
            "timestamp" : "",
            "description" : "",
            "handoverStatus" : ""
        ]
    let urlString = URL(string: APIDetails.BaseUrl + "api/123")!
    let url = (try? URLRequest(url: urlString, method: .post, headers: APIDetails.header))!
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartData) in
        
        let img1 = arrImage![0]
        let img2 = arrImage![1]
        let img3 = arrImage![2]

        multipartData.append(img1.pngData(), withName:"media1", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "file")
        multipartData.append(img2.pngData(), withName:"media2", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "file")
        multipartData.append(img3.pngData(), withName:"media3", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "file")
            
        
        for (key, value) in param {
            multipartData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

    }, with: url)
}
```

How do i upload every image and its details as a dictionary?

How do i add upload progress and result that shows if anything failed or not ?

I tried with

```
}, with: url,encodingCompletion:{
        EncodingResult in
        switch EncodingResult{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):

            print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")

        }        })
```

But it gives error `Extra argument 'encodingCompletion' in call`

(This is my first time trying to upload multipart form data, the code/part of it was taken from another answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, I have not tested in Alamofire(5.2)

```
let baseUrl = "your URL"
    let fullUrl = baseUrl + strUrl
    var headers : HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders(["Content-type" : "multipart/form-data"])
    if let header = header{
        headers = header
    }
    
    guard let url = try? URLRequest(url: fullUrl, method: .post, headers: headers) else {return}
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartData) in
        
        for i in 0 ..< arrImage.count{
            if let imageData = arrImage[i].pngData(){
                let mediaName = "media\(i + 1)"
                multipartData.append(imageData, withName:mediaName, fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "file")
            }
        }
      for (key, value) in parameter {
            multipartData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to: url).responseJSON(queue: .main, options: .allowFragments) { (response) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let value):
            print("Json: \(value)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }.uploadProgress { (progress) in
        print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
```

Comment: What does

 if let header = header{
        headers = header
    } , do ? Also it says ' Cannot find 'header' in scope '

Comment: @Zyfe3r headers added in URLRequest, Header contain information, token and meta-data that required for API request and response.

Comment: i figured it out. But somehow nothing works, i keep getting errors from backend about some exception. But same thing works perfectly on android !

Comment: @Zyfe3r share error and your code without it i can not figure it out, and this code work for me